# Amplify Hosting Build Error: `Could not initialize categories ... auth headless ... facebookAppIdUserPool, googleAppIdUserPool`

Tags: amazon-cognito, hosting, openid-connect, aws-amplify, api-key

I'm getting build errors when deploying the frontend application to my amplify web app. I've read the documentation on headless authentication [here](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/headless). My backend app successfully set up authentication with google and facebook dev keys. But I'm still unsure how to move past this error. I have tried add the environment variables of `googleAppIdUserPool`, `facebookAppIdUserPool`, etc.. to the environment variables of the project. I have also changed the frontend to be wrapped in `Authenticator.Provider`. But there is still no change.

Is this to do with my API using other types of authentication like API keys (which is not recommended for production)?
Or is this to do with a build script and environment variables not being in the correct place?

```
                                 # Starting phase: build
2023-02-28T21:11:27.145Z [INFO]: [0mAmplify AppID found: d3patqdt499898. Amplify App name is: tmtAmplifyApp[0m
2023-02-28T21:11:27.195Z [INFO]: [0mBackend environment dev found in Amplify Console app: tmtAmplifyApp[0m
2023-02-28T21:11:28.200Z [WARNING]: - Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud.
2023-02-28T21:11:29.423Z [WARNING]: - Building resource api/tmtamplifyapp
2023-02-28T21:11:29.703Z [INFO]: ⚠️ WARNING: owners may reassign ownership for the following model(s) and role(s): Booking: [owner]. If this is not intentional, you may want to apply field-level authorization rules to these fields. To read more: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/#per-user--owner-based-data-access.
2023-02-28T21:11:31.211Z [INFO]: ✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.
                                 Edit your schema at /codebuild/output/src269408372/src/tmtamplifyapp/amplify/backend/api/tmtamplifyapp/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /codebuild/output/src269408372/src/tmtamplifyapp/amplify/backend/api/tmtamplifyapp/schema
2023-02-28T21:11:31.214Z [WARNING]: - Building resource auth/tmtAmplifyApp
2023-02-28T21:11:31.263Z [WARNING]: - Building resource storage/s3tmtamplifyappstoragec3cc73b4
2023-02-28T21:11:31.322Z [WARNING]: ✔ Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.
2023-02-28T21:11:31.335Z [WARNING]: ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
2023-02-28T21:11:31.366Z [INFO]:  Could not initialize categories for 'dev': auth headless is missing the following inputParams facebookAppIdUserPool, facebookAppSecretUserPool, googleAppIdUserPool, googleAppSecretUserPool
2023-02-28T21:11:31.366Z [INFO]: Resolution: Review the error message and stack trace for additional information.
                                 Learn more at: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/troubleshooting/
2023-02-28T21:11:31.375Z [INFO]: Session Identifier: 29680280-992f-412f-a130-fabce1ed8550
2023-02-28T21:11:31.375Z [WARNING]: - Creating Zip
2023-02-28T21:11:31.389Z [INFO]: ✅ Report saved: /tmp/tmtAmplifyApp/report-1677618691379.zip
2023-02-28T21:11:31.389Z [INFO]: 
2023-02-28T21:11:31.389Z [WARNING]: - Sending zip
2023-02-28T21:11:31.390Z [INFO]: File at path: '/codebuild/output/src269408372/src/tmtamplifyapp/amplify/backend/amplify-meta.json' does not exist
2023-02-28T21:11:31.390Z [WARNING]: ✖ Sending zip
2023-02-28T21:11:31.408Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-02-28T21:11:31.409Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-02-28T21:11:31.409Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-02-28T21:11:31.409Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
```

Error: `Amplify Hosting Build Error: Could not initialize categories for 'dev': auth headless is missing the following inputParams facebookAppIdUserPool, googleAppIdUserPool`

Answer (score 0):

Reading on the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html, I found that I did not have `AMPLIFY_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID`, `AMPLIFY_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET`, `AMPLIFY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID`, and `AMPLIFY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` environment variables deployed into the AWS Amplify Project.